# Giving out 1000 answers at the same time in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

(I'm starting to hate already `while` in my school work...)

My issue now is, that I need to create a program where it asks from user a percentage for basketball throwing accuracy. And simulates 1000 throws - for every answer it gives hit or missed in result.

The example for program work if user enters 45 as percentage

```
throwing_accuracy = int(input("Enter throwing percentage")): 45

#Somewhere here would be while :
1. Throw hit
2. Throw hit
3. Throw hit
5. Throw missed
#.........#
999. Throw hit
1000. Throw hit
   #And then prints also a result how many hits there were
There were 458 hits
```

The program must be built using `while`, I read some hints that could use `if` and `else` statements and should `from random import randint` because there could be possibility to use a line `if randint(1,100) <= percentage`

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - I just know how the program should work, but have no idea how to build it...

Comment: This is far too broad for here then. This site is for helping you with existing, broken code. If you need general help, Reddit's `r/learnprogramming` might be a good place to check out. Note though, most places you visit will require you to specify what exactly you need help with. "How do I start this" is pretty broad, even on sites with a broad focus.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: you are not far off the mark, take a look at your other thread and read the solutions carefully, you'll get it eventually

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program such as this:

```
import random
percentage_accuracy = int(input("Input throwing accuracy here: "))
hits = 0
throws = 1
while throws <= 1000:
    if random.randint(1, 100) <= percentage_accuracy:
        hits += 1
        print("{}: Hit".format(x))
    else:
        print("{}: Miss".format(x))
    throws += 1
print("")
print("Player results:")
print("{} Hits".format(hits))
print("{} Misses".format(1000-hits))
```

it would be more efficient to use a for loop such as:

```
for throws in range(1,1001):
```

rather than:

```
throws = 1
while throws <= 1000:
    throws += 1
```